# Emacs + GDB + SCons + Step through Debugging

Tags: emacs, gdb, scons

When compiling a project via a makefile using the Emacs compile command, when gdb is run on the resultant binary the application can be stepped through. However, when building using a large project with SCons, attempting to step through does not work in that Emacs doesn't seem to know which files to load or how they're related to the binary.

What does one have to do to do step through in Emacs? If Emacs can't support SCons natively then how can this be done manually; make must be using some mechanism to alert Emacs to a file's presence.

Comment: Are you sure your make and scons compile options are the same? It sounds like your scons build is lacking debug symbols (in gcc, use the `-g` option).

Comment: @dave-bacher Please leave this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see your comment until just now. @dave-bacher didn't show your reply in my inbox. I think you have to use `@Dave Bacher` (or maybe just `@Dave`).

Comment: @DaveBacher I believe it's either the first name or no spaces.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your make and scons compile options are the same? It sounds like your scons build is lacking debug symbols (in gcc, use the `-g` option).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Scons.  I can't help but ask if you have done the [Scons IDEIntegration](http://www.scons.org/wiki/IDEIntegration) as given in the Working within Emacs and XEmacs section.  It says Scons builds in a different directory that Emacs does not look at by default, so you have to move the files to make Emacs look at them.  But that is for navigating through build error messages.  I hope it works for gdb too.

Comment: Yes, this is done. Dave Bacher had the answer, I'm only keeping this open to give him the opportunity to claim it.